# Is there a way to combine multiple route parameters into one in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-9

This particular route in my routes/web.php has five different parameters:

```
Route::get('/product/{size?}/{color}/{quantity?}/{style}/{prev_page}', 'ProductController@index')->name('product');
```

This means the URL looks pretty messy: `e.g. /product/null/navyblue/2/bootcut/basket`

Does Laravel provide a way to combine all the parameters into one GUID, so the user can use a url like `/product/f91caa59-01c4-459f-8e2f-242e31c1ab2a`?

Comment: Out of the box, no. But you can build that in yourself.

Comment: Ok cool. Thought there might be something built-in to do it.

Comment: Since it's an HTTP `GET` request, why don't you use query parameters instead? I.e: 
 `http://localhost/product?size=large&color=white&quantity=3&style=short&prev_page=2` Then, your route definition wouldn't have to be messy. I.e: `Route::get('/product', 'ProductController@index')->name('product');`

Comment: @aynber is there a php library to convert/encrypt long string to uuid string , just like Urbycoz asked ? and later decrypt it back to long string ?

Comment: @Win Not that I know of. I know Laravel has UUID generation built in now, but that doesn't encrypt anything.